# How to insert int value to String in adapter list view

Tags: java, android, string, android-arrayadapter

I am getting an error while inserting the method that returns the integer value into the array adapter list. It is saying in object can't applied.

My error:
[image]

Now I am unable to get the method and its value.
[image]

I am unable to access the getQuantity method.

The code:

```
public class FoodItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FoodItem> {

    private int qty  ;

    public FoodItemAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<FoodItem> androidFlavors) {
        // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
        // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
        // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
        // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
        super(context, 0, androidFlavors);
    }

    /**
     * Provides a view for an AdapterView (ListView, GridView, etc.)
     *
     * @param position    The position in the list of data that should be displayed in the
     *                    list item view.
     * @param convertView The recycled view to populate.
     * @param parent      The parent ViewGroup that is used for inflation.
     * @return The View for the position in the AdapterView.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }


        FoodItem currentFoodItem = getItem(position);


        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

        nameTextView.setText(currentFoodItem.getItemName());


        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);


        priceTextView.setText(currentFoodItem.getItemPrice());



        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);


        quantityTextView.setText(currentFoodItem.getQuantity());

        ImageView imgbutton = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_minus_img);
        imgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {
            public void onClick(View v)  {

                    qty = qty -1;

            }
        });
        ImageView imgbutton2 = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_minus_img);
        imgbutton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {
            public void onClick(View v)  {

                qty = qty  + 1;

            }
        });



        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews and an ImageView)
        // so that it can be shown in the ListView
        return listItemView;
    }

    public String getQuantity()
    {
        String strI = String.valueOf(qty);
        return strI;

    }
}
```

Comment: What does `currentFoodItem.toString(.)` method do and what parameter type it accepts?

Comment: Have you made a custom `.toString` method for whatever type `currentFoodItem` is? Could you post that?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke i did not did any custom .toString method

Comment: FoodItem currentFoodItem = getItem(position);   this is the currentFoodItem

Comment: @Avijit Karmakar's answer is probably what you want. Not sure why you're trying to call `toString` on `currentFoodItem`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for setting text to a view.

```
quantityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(displayQuantity()));
```

String.valueOf() method returns the string representation of the passed argument.

Like:

```
System.out.println("Return Value : " + String.valueOf(1.4));
```

It prints: Return Value : 1.4

```
System.out.println("Return Value : " + String.valueOf(true));
```

It prints: Return Value : true